# Error to connect ssl sockets with a CRLF json protocol

Tags: sockets, erlang, elixir

I'm trying to connect to a socket (ssl) using https://github.com/meh/elixir-socket

```
Socket.Web.connect! "stream-api.betfair.com", secure: true
```

But I'm facing with this error:

```
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:http_error, "{\"op\":\"connection\",\"connectionId\":\"203-270420013200-944388\"}\r\n"}
    (socket 0.3.13) lib/socket/web.ex:251: Socket.Web.connect!/3
```

But its not an error. The server accepts my connection, but elixir-socket returns an error. So what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The error in question happens [here](https://github.com/meh/elixir-socket/blob/master/lib/socket/web.ex#L251), meaning `Socket.Stream.recv!/2` had returned somewhat unexpected.

It is [delegated](https://github.com/meh/elixir-socket/blob/master/lib/socket/stream.ex#L71-L72) to `Socket.Stream.Protocol`.

Depending on whether you use `ssl` or not, it comes from [here](https://github.com/meh/elixir-socket/blob/master/lib/socket/stream.ex#L180-L182) or from [here](https://github.com/meh/elixir-socket/blob/master/lib/socket/stream.ex#L257-L259).

This library is ancient and AFAICT very strict. The only way to go further with I can think of, would be to fork it, examine the responses you expect to be correct, amend [handling of](https://github.com/meh/elixir-socket/blob/master/lib/socket/web.ex#L251) `Socket.Stream.recv!/2` to something that meets your requirements:

```rb
response =
  case Socket.Stream.recv!(client, global) do
    {:http_response, _, 101, _} -> :ok
    {:http_error, _json} -> :ok
    _ -> :error
  end
```

And handle it accordingly. Why your server responds in such a weird way is out of scope here.

Comment: I have no idea what “works for me” should mean in this context.

Comment: I just want to connect, but none of libs I've tested connects

Comment: [here](https://github.com/meh/elixir-socket/blob/22a65b2739611bf1f00135b72a21b256a16f645f/lib/socket/stream.ex#L258) is the problem.`:ssl.recv` returns `{:ok, {:http_error, "{\"op\":\"connection\",\"connectionId\":\"204-280420165409-1131618\"}\r\n"} }`

Comment: I pointed out in the answer above where is the problem. You are looking at non-banged version, banged version would return the value inside `{:ok, _}` tuple. The server responds with something like `{:ok, {:http_error, json}}`.

Comment: But what causes this `http_error`? Inside it has a "success" msg.

Comment: I believe `:ssl` does not understand what comes back from the server and `:http_error` is a sink-all handler, but I am not sure. In any case, for your request it’s success—so do treat it as a success. I am pretty sure after this match is handled , everything else would work.

Comment: Should I check it at [here](https://github.com/meh/elixir-socket/blob/master/lib/socket/web.ex#L251) or [here](https://github.com/meh/elixir-socket/blob/master/lib/socket/stream.ex#L257-L259)?

Comment: I addressed this question yesterday in the answer you are commenting on. AFAICT, `:ssl.recv` returns `{:ok, {:http_error, _}}` which is still `ok`. So I would patch the `case` as I mentioned above.

Comment: I've trying "force ok" but it needs `:http_header`. Maybe it needs header values to proceed.